# Moving section after screenshot leaving trace and not respecting screen section

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm trying to generate a screenshot and then I want a subsection of that screenshot to be able to move it. However I get some weird behavior as you can see in the following image.

[image]

The related code is the following:

```
import tkinter
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PIL import ImageTk


class Win(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, master)
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self._offsetx = 0
        self._offsety = 0

        # self.geometry(f"{screenWidth}x{screenHeight}")
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.clickwin)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.dragwin)
        self.bind('<Button-3>', self.close)

    def close(self, event):
        self.destroy()

    def dragwin(self, event):
        x = self.winfo_pointerx() - self._offsetx
        y = self.winfo_pointery() - self._offsety
        self.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")

    def clickwin(self, event):
        self._offsetx = event.x
        self._offsety = event.y


root = Win()

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()

im = ImageGrab.grab()
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, bg='white',
                        width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
canvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=tkinter.YES)
canvas.create_image(0, 0,
                    anchor=tkinter.NW, image=image)


def f():
    root.geometry("50x50")
    canvas.config(width=50, height=50)


canvas.after(2_000, f)
root.mainloop()
```

The undesired behavior is the dash/trace that the sliding section is leaving. The canvas and root should stay in just the small designed section and the rest of the screen should be the programs behind (which are not covered anymore by the screenshot.

As for my system, desktop environment: `xfce 4.14l` and OS `xubuntu 20.04`.

Comment: Seem that it works fine on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jizhihaoSAMA . For what you said, then it should be a bug on `tkinter` side while dealing with `X11`. I'll wait a little bit to see if somebody else can reproduce it with some linux distro or if they have encountered the error.